# Возможна ли пересборка андроид кода со более поздней версии API на новую

Tags: android

Работаю на движке(Clickteam Fusion). Там существует объект, который мешает компиляции, если версия API стоит выше 19. Однако есть другой объект, который не работает, если API ниже 23.

Существует ли какой-либо софт или сервис для пересборки кода на новый API?

Comment: Меняйте реализацию либо первого, либо второго объектов.

Comment: >Там существует объект, который мешает компиляции, если версия API стоит выше 19

Что значит мешает? Выдает предупреждение *deprecation* или что то еще?